# Implement 3-D Secure Payment authentication in DotnetNuke DNN 7

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dnn9

I would like to implement 3-d secure payment authentication in DotnetNuke DNN 7 , Can you help how to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question.

If you are talking about payments for an ecommerce solution, you need a shopping solution that supports payment providers, e.g. [OpenStore](https://github.com/openstore-ecommerce/OpenStore), and implement the payment provider.

If you are talking about authentication for a website, have a look at the authentication provider concept, study the source code for different solutions and write your own authentication provider.